# How Windows determines what source port to use?

Tags: windows, http, request, port

For a typical HTTP request how does Windows determine what port to send the request from and is it possible to choose a certain port?

Comment: i think that depends on the software you use to make the request (usually a browser). why do you want to do that?

Comment: If the software lets Windows choose the port, it will always be in the dynamic/private port range (49152 through 65535).  The precise algorithm used to choose one of these ports isn't documented AFAIK and is subject to change.

Answer (score -1):

If you are typing this into a browser, the browser is picking the port or it is automatically assigned by the operating system. If you are using C language, you can specify the port for an HTTP request when you bind to the IP address. The IP:Port combination is unique and can't be used by more than one program. Maybe you are trying to select the destination port. In a browser URL, you would type example.com:8080 to select the **destination** port. Please give more background information.